# Android - How can I achieve this Google Maps animation?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

This is how I'm currently using my google map;

```
        mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mapFragment.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mapFragment.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mapFragment.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        mapFragment.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
        mapFragment.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
```

It produces a full screen map which for some reason is completely zoomed into the ocean so the map is just one big, blue pixel until you keep zooming out.

What I want to do:

- When this activity gets opened, the map should have the user's location in the center, and the map should be as zoomed out as possible (as if you are lookin at a 2D globe)
- The map should then zoom/animate into the player's location to give the same effect as when you press the location button on the top right of the map.

I have looked online, tried a few things and haven't had any luck with this. If anybody can walk me through this or give me a link to a nice guide it would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you want, you should:
1) get the user's position, you can use the last known position so that your main activity would not hang and wait for the GPS return a location.

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService
            (Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location getLastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation
            (LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
```

2) set the zoom level to 1, which is the smallest zoom level, the `2D globe`; also you can center the map using the user location too.

```
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(1));
```

3) animate the camera to zoom into the user location with a zoom level 20 (the largest zoom level). One thing to notice is that, you might want to wait until the `2D globe` maps is loaded so that user can see the zoom happens.

```
        googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            public void onMapLoaded() {
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(userLocation.getLatitude(), userLocation.getLongitude()))
                        .zoom(20)
                        .build()));
            }
        });
```

I tried that and it works fine for me. Let me know if it is unclear, and hope it helps.

[image]